# Telegram API encode message to be sent

Tags: php, api, urlencode, telegram-bot

What is the encode parameters url of telegram? I used `urlencode ($message)` but on mobile the message is not decoded from the app. **If I don't use the encode for the message , I get an error

> gateway (error 501 or 502**, I don't remember)

.

The example url is that I do `https://api.telegram.org/bot$token/sendMessage?chat_id=$chat_id&text=$message` where `$message` is my text to be decoded

Answer (score 1):

just make an array and use `http_build_query` [method](http://php.net/http_build_query). It also handles the encoding for you.

An example would be like this:

```
$queryStringArray = [
  'chat_id' => $chat_id,
  'text'    => $message,
];


$url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$token.'/sendMessage?'.http_build_query($queryStringArray);
```

I'm using this exact way in my micro Telegram bot app [here](https://github.com/Ardakilic/Telegram-bot-php).

Comment: Typo - http_build_query($queryString); not $queryArray